# How show video poster after pausing it in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array of videos, each video has an id and I use it in my HTML file like this:

```
<div class="p-3" *ngFor="let video of videoList; let i = index">
  <video #videoPlayer (ended)="onPlayVideoEnded(video.id)" poster="assets/video/screenshot/{{video.id}}.PNG">
    <source src="assets/video/{{video.id}}.mp4" type="video/mp4" *ngIf="selectedPlayVideoIndex === i" />
  </video>
  <img class="hc-play_video" src="assets/img/play.png" *ngIf="selectedPlayVideoIndex !== i" (click)="onPlayVideoClick(i)">
</div>
```

and here's my ts file:

```
onPlayVideoClick(index: number) {
    const videoplayer = this.videoplayer.toArray();
    if (this.selectedPlayVideoIndex > -1) {
      videoplayer[this.selectedPlayVideoIndex].nativeElement.pause();
      videoplayer[this.selectedPlayVideoIndex].nativeElement.currentTime = 0;
    }
    this.selectedPlayVideoIndex = index;
    videoplayer[index].nativeElement.play();
}
```

After playing multiple videos, they stuck after the first frame of video. But what I want is to show the poster image again. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing you should do is pretty simple, you add `.load()` function after you're pausing the video.
Something like this:

```
onPlayVideoClick(index: number) {
    const videoplayer = this.videoplayer.toArray();
    if (this.selectedPlayVideoIndex > -1) {
        videoplayer[this.selectedPlayVideoIndex].nativeElement.pause();
        videoplayer[this.selectedPlayVideoIndex].nativeElement.currentTime = 0;
        videoplayer[this.selectedPlayVideoIndex].nativeElement.load(); // here
    }
    this.selectedPlayVideoIndex = index;
    videoplayer[index].nativeElement.play();
}
```

Then it will show poster image after pausing the video.